# How to select the columns of a binary feature matrix to obtain minimal overlap

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, discrete-optimization, mixed-integer-programming

Suppose you have a (rather sparse) binary matrix with $M$ rows and $N$ columns.
The columns represent objects, the rows represent features of the objects.
A $1$ in the matrix indicates that the corresponding object has the corresponding feature.

You can apply a logical 'or' to each row of the matrix, by which any row where at least one element is $1$ gives $1$, otherwise $0$.
Let vector $v$ of length $M$ be the result of the above operation applied to the matrix.
For the above defined 'initial' matrix, $v$ is a vector of $1$'s, i.e. each feature is found in at least one object.

**The goal is to select $n \le \frac N 2$ columns of this matrix, such that if you calculate $v_1$ for the resulting submatrix (with only those selected columns), and $v_2$ for the submatrix of all the remaining columns, the scalar product $v_1 \cdot v_2$ (i.e. the 'overlap') is minimal.**

In other words, you want to partition the set of $N$ objects into a set $S_1$ of size $n$ and its complementary set $S_2$ of size $N-n$, such that there are as few features of the objects in $S_1$ in common with the features of the objects in $S_2$.

How would you approach this theoretically / computationally?

I found a way to write this as a linear programming problem.
It works, but for $N > 5000$ it becomes too slow to be of any practical use. I might need to do this for $N$ in the order of $10^6$.

As far as approximate methods go, I tried to make the initial matrix as 'close to diagonal' as possible by sorting the columns, after which I scanned all possible sets of $n$ consecutive columns to find the one giving the smallest overlap.
I am not talking about a proper diagonal matrix, which I believe can only be square.
What I mean is, I tried to rearrange the columns in such a way to have contiguous sequences of columns with $1$'s 'more or less the same area' when you look vertically across the features.
It might work approximately and it is certainly faster than LP, but I am not sure I am taking the best approach.

Any suggestions / ideas?

Thanks!

---

**EDIT:** the linear programming formulation used previously, which seems to be superseded in terms of computational efficiency by the one suggested by @RobPratt below.

\begin{align}
\min \sum_{i=1}^M y_{i,1}+y_{i,2} \\
\sum_{j=1}^N x_j = n \tag1 \\
\sum_{j=1}^N x_j a_{i,j} - y_{i,1} \sum_{j=1}^N a_{i,j} &\le 0 &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,M\}$} \tag2 \\
\sum_{j=1}^N x_j a_{i,j} - y_{i,1} \sum_{j=1}^N a_{i,j} &\ge 1 - \sum_{j=1}^N a_{i,j} &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,M\}$} \tag3 \\
\sum_{j=1}^N x_j a_{i,j} + y_{i,2} \sum_{j=1}^N a_{i,j} &\ge \sum_{j=1}^N a_{i,j} &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,M\}$} \tag4 \\
\sum_{j=1}^N x_j a_{i,j} + y_{i,2} \sum_{j=1}^N a_{i,j} &\le 2 \sum_{j=1}^N a_{i,j} -1 &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,M\}$} \tag5 \\
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Here is an integer programming formulation, perhaps different than yours.  Let $a_{i,j}$ be the entry in row $i$, column $j$ of your matrix.  For $j\in\{1,\dots,N\}$, let binary decision variable $x_j$ indicate whether object $j$ appears in $S_1$.  For $i\in\{1,\dots,M\}$ and $k\in\{1,2\}$, let binary decision variable $y_{i,k}$ indicate whether feature $i$ appears in $S_k$.  The problem is to minimize the quadratic objective function $\sum_{i=1}^M y_{i,1} y_{i,2}$ subject to linear constraints
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^N x_j &= n \tag1 \\
x_j &\le y_{i,1} &&\text{for $i$ and $j$ such that $a_{i,j}=1$} \tag2 \\
1-x_j &\le y_{i,2} &&\text{for $i$ and $j$ such that $a_{i,j}=1$} \tag3
\end{align}
You can relax $y_{i,k}\in\{0,1\}$ to $y_{i,k}\ge 0$, and doing so might improve the solve time.  The resulting problem is mixed integer quadratic programming (MIQP).

---

You can also linearize as follows.  Introduce binary decision variable $z_i$ to represent the product $y_{i,1} y_{i,2}$.  The problem is to minimize the linear objective function $\sum_{i=1}^M z_i$ subject to linear constraints $(1)$, $(2)$, $(3)$, and
\begin{align}
y_{i,1} + y_{i,2} - 1 &\le z_i &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,M\}$} \tag4
\end{align}
Again, you can relax $z_i\in\{0,1\}$ to $z_i \ge 0$ if it helps.  Now use a mixed integer linear programming (MILP) solver.

---

An idea for possible improvement is to aggregate $(2)$ and $(3)$ (separately) to reduce the number of constraints.  This will weaken the LP relaxation but speed up the underlying LP solves so might yield an overall improvement in solve time.
\begin{align}
\sum_{j:a_{i,j}=1} x_j &\le \left(\sum_j a_{i,j}\right) y_{i,1} &&\text{for all $i$} \tag{2$'$} \\
\sum_{j:a_{i,j}=1} (1-x_j) &\le \left(\sum_j a_{i,j}\right) y_{i,2} &&\text{for all $i$} \tag{3$'$}
\end{align}
OK, this turns out to be equivalent to your $(2)$ and $(4)$.  So maybe try your formulation without your $(3)$ and $(5)$.

---

To instead maximize $\sum_i z_i$, you can omit $y_{i,k}$ and replace $(2)$, $(3)$, and $(4)$ with:
\begin{align}
\sum_{j:a_{i,j}=1} x_j &\ge z_i &&\text{for all $i$} \tag{2$''$} \\
\sum_{j:a_{i,j}=1} (1-x_j) &\ge z_i &&\text{for all $i$} \tag{3$''$}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you @RobPratt !
In my case $n$ is chosen by the user, so constraint (1) actually ends in $= n$. In fact, if we used the one you mention, couldn't the program simply always choose $n=1$, and in particular an object with as many unique (not shared with other objects) features as possible?
I do need to use a linear solver because so far I have not been able to get a license for the quadratic one (IBM's CPLEX), so I will try out your linear formulation, which looks slightly different from mine.

Comment: Just wanted to report that from some initial tests your method works much faster than mine. So thank you very much again for suggesting it! I will see how it scales. If I find the time I will report my own formulation, for reference. It uses $N+2M$ variables, as opposed to yours that has $N+3M$ variables. The number of constraints is also much larger in your case. Maybe that explains why your method is faster, who knows.

Comment: Further development. In fact, there is no need to use the $z_i$ variables or constraint (4). An optimal solution is indeed one where the overlap, i.e. the sum of $z_i$, is minimal, but given that $M = \sum_{i=1}^M y_{i,1} + y_{i,2} - z_i$, and $M$ is a constant, $min \sum_{i=1}^M z_i$ is the same as $min \sum_{i=1}^M y_{i,1} + y_{i,2}$. I tried it out and it seems to work.

Comment: @user6376297, I agree that $z_i$ and $(4)$ can be eliminated by your objective change.  Also, you might experiment with aggregating $(2)$ and $(3)$ (separately).  That will weaken the LP relaxation but reduce the problem size so might yield a net improvement in solve time.

Comment: That's interesting, thanks! I will try if I find the time.
Another thing that occurred to me was: what if I wanted the *maximal* overlap? I think constraints (2) and (3) are only implying that if an object variable is 1, all features variables of that object are also 1, but it does not stop feature variables from being 1 even when no object bearing those features is selected. This is not a problem for a minimisation, because feature variables that don't have to be 1 won't be. For a maximisation instead the solver would probably set all feature variables to 1 regardless.

Comment: Oh, OK, I just saw your latest comment. I could remove (3) and (5) from my method, indeed. I had included them to ensure that I could do max as well as min without changing the code too much. But your method was faster in all cases... maybe my solver (Rsymphony) prefers many constraints and does its own aggregation...

Comment: I saw your edit concerning maximising the overlap. That's really clever, thanks! So perhaps it is worth writing two slightly different pieces of code for the two types of tasks, if it saves me $2M$ variables. And it is actually very interesting that only changing the direction of the optimisation should change so radically the way this works. Now the problem I still need to solve is how to make this work for very large $N$ and $M$. I'll probably need to go for some iterative method.

Comment: Are you likely to have any duplicate rows or columns?

Comment: Duplicate columns = pairs of objects with the same set of features; this is possible, but only for some applications; in the most general case each object has a unique set of features. Duplicate rows = pairs of features that appear in the same set of objects; not sure about this, might be, but I'd guess it is not very frequent.

Comment: For future reference, I found an iterative method to do this without using LP. Suppose all objects are initially in set $S_2$, and $S_1$ is empty. $S_2$ has all the features, and $S_1$ has no features. Loop through all objects and find the one that, if moved to $S_1$, either causes the disappearance of all its features from $S_2$, or gives the smallest difference between the number of features appearing in $S_1$ and the number of features disappearing from $S_2$. Continue until $S_1$ has $n$ objects. I tried this out and it does a pretty decent job, although it does not guarantee optimality.

Comment: A desirable extension of this concept would be the creation of more than 2 sets, but then I think the overlap and the number of unique features in each set are not as simply correlated as here. Would be interesting to investigate though, as the production of feature-disjoint sets is a very useful task in many fields, and at the moment is mostly done by clustering, which does not always allow the same level of control on the final set sizes.

Comment: As an extension of your greedy heuristic, after $|S_1|=n$ you can then look for “2-opt” swaps to replace one object in $S_1$ with one in $S_2$. Also, you can use any integer feasible solution to warm start the MILP solver.